# Unity doesn't load, no dasher but can see desktop icons and home ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher, unity-dash

I am using ubuntu 13.10 since 8-9 months and I had never faced problem as such. Yesterday I installed some regular updates of ubuntu 13.10 ..everything was working fine but this morning when I started my laptop, I was not able to see unity nor dasher. I followed all the steps mentioned in this link. [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) . But no luck.

I can see my desktop icons. I installed compiz settling manager and when i go and enable unity plugin, screen blinks as it's loading something but nothing turns up. 
(unity is already installed, ccsm is also already installed and unity plugin is enabled)

this didnt work I tried other thins like.

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity

rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

and also deleted `.Xautority`

I also installed

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity ubuntu-desktop

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && unity --reset-icons &disown
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: have you tried just running `unity` from terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)

Comment: yeah I have tried running unity from terminal. When I run unity from terminal screen blinks but no change.. Sorry cause of reputation I am not able to post the images

Comment: Can you post somewhere else and add the link?

Comment: here is link http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=112aluv&s=8#.U5FP7fldWSp .. you can see there are 2 white boxes .1 bigger white box of terminal. 2 one is of weather widget, Somehow they are coming white too. but when restart couple of time terminal open normally but sometimes it comes white.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue, have you enabled alternative drivers?

Comment: I could not figure out the problem!! I clean installed 14.04. :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue & I tried all the options but nothing really worked for me either, after fighting around 6hrs I found solution on my own,it is kind of tricky lot of ppl said ccsm will work, but for me ccsm is not working too. it was throughing errors while executing command

```
$ccsm
```

so first go to 
 1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.then install ccsm using below command:

```
       sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

on desktop open a folder, if you dont have one.just create it,and open it
then from there press backspace untill you reach to root dir from there navigate to

```
       /usr/bin/
```

from there search for gnome-terminal file, once you find double click on it, it will launch gnome terminal from there enter the command

```
     ccsm
```

it will launch compizconfig-settings-manager, there search for 'ubuntu unity plugin' click on it then enable unity plugin by checking it. now you will have unity and dash on top. Thanks all